# Solving a tricky equation $4x^3-5x^2-5 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots-of-cubics

How does one solve $4x^3-5x^2-5 = 0$? I've tried the substitution $y = x - \frac{5}{12}$ but then I ended up with this monster of an equation: $864y^3 - 450y -1205 = 0$. Now I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can apply [Cardano's method](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kkreith/tutorials/sample.lesson/cardano.html) to the depressed cubic

Comment: My normal attack of such a cubic is to make my first try the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), where I manually use a pocket calculator to check each possible rational root.  In this instance, it looks like this approach will fail.  Then, my fall back strategy is Cardano's method, as indicated by the comment of @user170231.

Comment: Graph it and see with what values of $x$ have $y=0$

Comment: try $x=1.66846$ I used graphing calculator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula) (even I don't use it, there's a high chance of errors), here's a similar method:

Let $t = \sqrt[3]{a+b}+\sqrt[3]{a-b}$. Then,
$$t^3 = 2a+3t\sqrt[3]{a^2-b^2}$$which can be shown simply by cubing both sides. This means that $\sqrt[3]{a+b}+\sqrt[3]{a-b}$ is a (real, assuming $|a|>|b|$ and both $a$ and $b$ were reals) solution of the depressed cubic
$$t^3 - 3t\sqrt[3]{a^2-b^2} - 2a = 0$$

We can use this property in the question. Make a substitution $x = 1/y$ to get (note that zero is not a solution of the original equation):
$$4(1/y)^3 - 5(1/y)^2 - 5 = 0$$
$$y^3 + y - \frac 45 = 0$$
Here, $a = 2/5$ and hence $b^2 = 133/675$.
Thus,
$$y = \sqrt[3]{2/5+\sqrt{133/675}}+\sqrt[3]{2/5-\sqrt{133/675}}$$And it can be shown using calculus that this is the only real solution.

[Computed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Power%5B%5C%2840%29Cbrt%5BDivide%5B2%2C5%5D%2BSqrt%5BDivide%5B133%2C675%5D%5D%5D%2BCbrt%5BDivide%5B2%2C5%5D-Sqrt%5BDivide%5B133%2C675%5D%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C-1%5D&assumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22) $1/y$ using WA to get:
$$x = \frac{1}{12}\left(5+\sqrt[3]{1205-60\sqrt{399}}+\sqrt[3]{5(241+12\sqrt{399})}\right)\approx 1.688458990229318741$$
same as the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Please, do not use Cardano method if you want to avoid poor looking results !*

Following the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), you have
$$\Delta =-13300 \qquad p=-\frac{25}{48}\qquad q=-\frac{1205}{864}$$ So, one real root.

Using the hyperbolic solution, the real root is
$$x=\frac{5}{12} \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{241}{25}\right)\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer but I don't know why but I like to share the value of $x$ that satisfies the given equation. The equation has only one real root and that is $$\frac{1}{12}\left(5+\sqrt[3]{1205-60\sqrt{399}}+\sqrt[3]{5(241+12\sqrt{399})}\right)$$

I wonder if anyone can find it by hand.

Comment: I thought after hitting 2k reputation, you'd change your name to "MathStackexchangeIsVeryGood"....

Comment: @DS I wanted that too...but it says I can change by name once a month...and so I've to wait till 10th April

Answer (score 2):

This one does not require WA, but requires you to be good at complicated arithmetic:

You have already got
$$864y^3 - 450y -1205 = 0 \iff y^3 - \frac{25}{48}y - \frac{1205}{864}=0$$(not the same $y$ in my previous answer). Again, $t = \sqrt[3]{a+b}+\sqrt[3]{a-b}$ is a solution of $$t^3 - 3t\sqrt[3]{a^2-b^2} - 2a = 0$$Comparing, we get $a = \frac{1205}{1728}$, and hence $b^2 = \frac{1436400}{2985984}$. Thus, $b = \frac{60\sqrt{399}}{1728}$.
We get:
$$y = \sqrt[3]{\frac{1205}{1728}+\frac{60\sqrt{399}}{1728}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1205}{1728}-\frac{60\sqrt{399}}{1728}}= \frac1{12}\left(\sqrt[3]{1205+60\sqrt{399}}+\sqrt[3]{1205-60\sqrt{399}}\right)$$
Substituting $x = y+\frac5{12}$ gives the answer:
$$\boxed{x = \frac1{12}\left(5+\sqrt[3]{1205+60\sqrt{399}}+\sqrt[3]{1205-60\sqrt{399}}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach very similar to Cardano's method. It uses a series of substitutions.

Given $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$.

Divide by A to get $x^3+Mx^2+Nx+F$

Note that from the symmetry of the cubic, there's a vertical line of symmetry passing directly between the critical points. If you shift the curve with a variable substitution, you can get rid of the quadratic term.

Critical Points: $x= \frac{-2M\pm \sqrt{M^2-12F}}{6}$. Midpoint: $x=-M/3$

Note: Multiply the y values of the two critical points. If this is positive you have one real solution, negative, you have two.

Let $u=x-M/3$ and substitute. You'll get something of the form: $u^3+pu+q=0$.

Now execute another change of variable: $u=(z+G/z)$

Then $u^3+pu+q= z^3+3z^2(G/z)+3z(G/z)^2+(G/z)^3+pz+pG/z+q=0$

Collect like terms and simplify:

$z^3+3Gz+3G/z+G^3/z^3+pz+pG/z+q=z^3+(3G+p)z+(3G+p)/z+G^3/z^3+q=0$

Let $G=-p/3$ to cancel the two terms in the middle, then multiply by $z^3$ to get: $z^6+qz^3+p=0$

Now $z^3=\frac{-q\pm\sqrt{q^2-4p}}{2}$ , $u=z-\frac{p}{3z}$, and $x=u+M/3$